# I am getting error Unable to retrieve object while using PageReference.getContentAsPdf() . I am getting this error only for partner community user

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, apex-webservice

```
WebService static String send_InvoicePdf(String invid){
    try{
        if(String.isNotBlank(invid) ){
            String query = 'SELECT ';
            for(String s : fields(Invoice__c.getSobjectType())){
                query += s+', ';
            }
            query += ' Contact__r.Name';
            query = query.removeEnd(', ');
            query += ' FROM Invoice__c WHERE Id =:invid';
            System.debug('query==='+query);
            Invoice__c record = Database.query(query);
            EmailTemplate salesInvoice = [SELECT Id, Subject, body, HtmlValue FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Sales Invoice Email'];
            EmailTemplate finalInvoice = [SELECT Id, HtmlValue,body,  Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Final Invoice Email'];
            EmailTemplate proformaInvoice = [SELECT Id, HtmlValue, body, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Proforma Invoice Email'];
            /*record.Email_to_MD__c = true;
            if(!record.Email_to_MD__c){
                Update record;
            }
            */
            System.debug('*************record *****************'+record );

            PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/InvoicePDF?scontrolCaching=1&id='+record.Id);
            //pdf.getParameters().put('Id',record.Id);
            system.debug('id is'+pdf);
            // the contents of the attachment from the pdf
            Blob body;

            try {
                //returns the output of the page as a PDF
                body = pdf.getContentAsPdf();
                //need to pass unit test -- current bug  
            }catch (Exception e) {
                body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
            }
            //Added by divya 2 Jan,2018
            String templateId;
           /* Decimal d = record.Remaining_Amount__c;
            String sRemaining;
            if (!string.valueof(d.format()).right(3).contains('.')){
                sRemaining = string.valueof(d.format()) + '.00';
            }else if (string.valueof(d.format()).right(2).contains('.')){
                sRemaining = string.valueof(d.format()) + '0';
            }else {
                sRemaining = string.valueof(d.format());
            }*/
            String subject;
            String attchName;
            If(record.Invoice_Type__c=='Proforma Invoice'){
                subject = renderTemplate(record, proformaInvoice.Subject);
                templateId = proformaInvoice.Id;
                attchName = record.Invoice_Number_Text__c + ' Proforma Invoice.pdf';
            }
            else if(record.Invoice_Type__c=='Sales Invoice'){
                subject = renderTemplate(record, salesInvoice.Subject);
                templateId = salesInvoice.Id;
                attchName = record.Invoice_Number_Text__c + ' Sales Invoice.pdf';
            }
            else if(record.Invoice_Type__c=='Final Invoice'){
                subject = renderTemplate(record, finalInvoice.Subject);
                templateId = finalInvoice.Id;
                attchName = record.Invoice_Number_Text__c + ' Final Invoice.pdf';
            }

            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
            attach.setFileName(attchName);
            attach.setInline(false);
            attach.Body = body;


            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, null, record.Id);
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setSubject(subject);
            String toaddress = record.Email__c;
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {toaddress};
            mail.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
           // mail.setHtmlBody(testMail.getHtmlBody());
            mail.setSubject(subject);

            if( String.isNotBlank( record.Additional_Email__c ) ){
                String[] CCAddress = new String[]{};
                CCAddress = record.Additional_Email__c.split(';');
                mail.setCCAddresses(CCAddress);
            }
            mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach }); 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

            Attachment att = new Attachment(
                ContentType = 'application/pdf',
                Name = 'Invoice.pdf',
                Body = body,
                parentId = invid
            );
        }
        return null;

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('*********Error*************'+e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

this method is called upon button click, it works fine for non partner community user

> Error : Unable to retrieve object  Line : body =
>   pdf.getContentAsPdf();

Here is the button code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/apex.js")}

var em ='{!Invoice__c.Email__c }' ;

var txt;
var r = confirm("Do you want to continue sending Invoice to the following email -"+'{!Invoice__c.Email__c }');
if (r == true) {
if(em!='' || em!=null){
var error = document.getElementById('errorDiv_ep');
var ParentName = sforce.apex.execute("Email_Pdf","send_InvoicePdf", {'invid':'{!Invoice__c.Id}'});
ParentName=ParentName+'';
var n = ParentName.indexOf("http");
txt = "Email sent..";
alert(txt);

}
else {
txt = "Email Id not found..";
alert(txt);
}
}
location.reload ();
```

Comment: Make sure the Page is enabled for the Community User Profile

Comment: @Ideasforce It is already enabled for community profile and also have access to all objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using vf page to invoke apex from button instead of calling apex method from execute javascript (Webservice method).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a question for the same problem (with a proposed solution)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/object-not-found-issue-in-pdf-attachment-visualforce-page-for-an-email).

From the aforementioned post:

> When you pass the ID to the PDF controller directly after the insert
> from the same controller method the record is not available. You can
> output the ID in the PDF and see that it is clearly getting passed
> through. You can select the record back in the method where you did
> the insert, but for some reason the record is not available in the PDF
> controller. I suspect there is something going on behind the scenes
> with how the transactions and/or transaction contexts are handled.

In your case the update line may be the problem, and my guess is you can work it around with the same proposed solution. i.e.: **After the update, forward to a blank page that gets the pdf and sends the email**.

Comment: Also note you are updating the Invoice__c record with no changes, you may want to include the commented "record.Email_to_MD__c = true;" line within the if statement that follows

Comment: Hi , if you see closely the whole code for update is commented already so update is not the issue

Comment: Ah! Sorry I didn't notice it was all commented. I guess the "record" result of the dynamic query is also not resolved when you call the getContentAsPDF. Try changing "record.Id" for "invid" in the URL for the new PageReference

Comment: I already tried with "invid", but it results the same, and I am sure "record.id" is resolved as I saw debug logs of VF page's  controller